# Auto increment by group in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, modelbuilder

I want to calculate auto increment a field name by group order Column "ID" into column "Name" in ModelBuilder and my input is shapefile.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a simple model and copying some prepared code from the help file.

Here is an input table, note that the ID column values are not necessarily sequential.

[image: Sample data]

The model is:

[image: Model]

The iterator is grouping by the ID field and the calculate field tool is set up as:

[image: Tool set up]

The code is found on the help file [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F3F8CD77A9F647ABBA678A76ADB86E15)

The final output is:

[image: Output]