# Incrementing value based on grouped field using QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I've got a dataset of buildings roof segments in shapefiles. I need to sequentially number the roof segments from 1 to n of each building.

Is there a way to do it with the QGIS field calculator?

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

It's pretty similar to an ArcPy question: [Auto increment by group in ArcGIS ModelBuilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374120/auto-increment-by-group-in-arcgis-modelbuilder)

Comment: Another answer a little bit faster :
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433973/auto-increment-associated-with-field-type-in-qgis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
array_find(array_agg("BUILDING"||'_'||-$id,"BUILDING"),"BUILDING"||'_'||-$id)+1
```

Result:

[image]