# Assigning incrementing id for each feature group in attributes with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, grouping

I have a layer with a repeating field `name`, thus different groups of features (I also have a numerical `group` field). How can I add a field `group_id`, using QGIS expressions? What I want is kind of a uniqe identifier **per group**, counting from 1 to the last element contained in the group (see screenshot).

What I tried: Using `array_length (array_agg( "group", "group"))`, I get the number of features per group (field `no_in_group`). With  generate_series `(1, [features per group])`, I get an array, counting from 1 to the last no. of each group.

However, I'm stuck how to assign each element of the array to one feature of the group. I suppose that `array_foreach ()` will do the job, but I'm unsure how to use it in this case.

*Screenshot: the field with red outline is what I want to get: a unique, incrementing id, starting from 1 for each `group`. Here, I introduced the values manually to make clear what I'm looking for:*
[image]

Comment: Like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/376724/107424?

Comment: Great, that is the solution I was looking for. I'll accept it if you add it.

Comment: I just came with the same solution as the other post, so duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for a QGIS expression solution but I came up with a quick Python solution which does the job. Just run this as a script while the layer is active.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

#order by group
request = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()
clause = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause("group", ascending=False)
orderby = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
request.setOrderBy(orderby)

current_group = None
last_group = None
with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
        
        current_group = f["group"]
        if current_group != last_group:
            id = 1
        else:
            id += 1

        last_group = current_group
        f["group_id"] = id
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

The result:

[image]

Note: Run this in the script editor window, not the console.
[image]

Comment: There is an `IndentationError: unexpected indent
        f["group_id"] = id`

Comment: Click "Show editor". Then paste it in the editor window and run.

Comment: It won't work from the console, I will update the answer

Comment: Runs! I first got an error `KeyError: 'group_id'`, than manually created a field `group_id`. After that, it worked! I vote up, but won't accept the answer for the moment not to discourage other solutions with QGIS expressions.

Comment: Yes, the script assumes a `group_id` field already exists.