# Automatic calculate row_number for all category field by QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm looking for a workaround or trick to calculate row_number function for more than 100 category in one step rather than do it manually for each category by QGIS.

Update:
I have POIs layer and in sub_category field contains more than 100 values, I want to calculate row_ number for each this category automatically rather than one by one.

Comment: This isn't clear to me. Do you want to replace categories with numbers? Or add row numbers to records, but counting each category separately? Or something else? Can you show an example input and the correct output?

Comment: isnt `@row_number` the same for all categories? Take a look into in `refactor fields` as batch process or pyqgis solutions.

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376724/increment-value-based-on-grouped-field?

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Thank you very much @MrXsquared, yeah that is what I want but if possible to restart the increment for each category, it will be great.

Comment: You just need to replace `"BUILDING"` with the fieldname of your category-field in the expression from the answer. That should do it.

Comment: Yeah I did it, but unfortunately "BUILDING" field on the other hand in  my layer it contains  words not numbers

Comment: Sorry bro, it's working fine

Comment: Thank you very much