# Auto-increment associated with field type in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am hoping to build a field in one of my QField forms that auto-increments a number associated with a particular value from a different field.

ie. if field "Sampler" has value "AA", a new field, "Station_ID" will auto-populate AA-001. If another point is taken by sampler "AA", the "Station_ID" will auto-increment to AA-002. If another point is taken by sampler "BB", the "Station_ID" will auto-populate to BB-001.

This will allow me to associated a unique station ID with each individual samplers collected data.

I'm working on QGIS 3.22.5

How can I complete this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, configure the form for **Station_ID** this way

[image]

basically is to turn off the editable option, turn on apply defaults on update and paste this expression in the default value:

```
format(
    '%1-%2',
    "Sampler",
    with_variable(
        'n',
        array_count(
            array_agg(
                "Sampler"
                ),
                "Sampler"
            ) + 1,
        lpad(@n, 3, '0')
        )
    )
```

Comment: you rock! Thank-you!

Comment: Thanks. It is working well but doesn not seem to work on qfield. Do you have any ideas why this might not work?

Comment: Another option than the array methods would have been count("sampler",group_by:="sampler"), using count_distinct would have been an extra safety too.

Answer (score 2):

Python code does not work in QField. So you need an expression.

Default of 'Station-ID' should be as follows:

```
sampler||'-'||LPAD(count(sampler=sampler),3,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Kadir. I finally had a chance to test this a bit more and this code produces the default Station-ID "sampler"-000. On QGIS it automatically increments by sampler. ie. AA-000, AA-001, AA-002, but when exported to QField the default still does not auto-increment. Instead, each time a new point is made with the same sampler, the Station-ID stays at AA-000. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same thing than you. Add +1 to increment. This is the expression I use :

```
coalesce("sampler") || '-' || coalesce(lpad((count("sampler",("sampler")) + 1),3,0)))
```

It seems to me that QGIS counts when you create a station while Qfield counts after you saved your station.
But I have my own problem. Please tell me if you have the same or maybe someone will find a solution :
By using my expression, because the default value is applying on update, all my stations are renamed automatically in background when I use Qfield (but it works fine in QGIS). For example, if I had three AA station (AA-001, AA-002 and AA-003), every three stations become AA-003.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your willingness to provide an answer to a question. If you encounter a problem, please open your own topic. Please do not ask questions in answers to other people's questions.