# UpdateCursor with multiple loops in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a feature class and I need to renumber from 1 and increase by 1 for a group of features. To do that, I need to define these groups (based on atributes of a field) and for each group make an update cursor.
My problem is that in my code, just the first group of features are updated and the others not. Where is my mistake?

This is what I have today

[image]

and this is what I want

[image: and this is what I want]

My code:

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"C:\Users\Moshe\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\D1"
Layer = "Layer"
RefName = "RefName"
startNumber = 1
listValue = []


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyrName, Layer) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        value = row[0]
        listValue.append(row[0])
    list = list(dict.fromkeys(listValue))
    print(list)

Layer2 = "Layer"
RefName2 = "RefName"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, [RefName2, Layer2]) as cursor2:
    for i in list:
        print (i)
        for row2 in cursor2:
                if row2[1] in str(i):
                    row2[0] = startNumber
                    startNumber = startNumber + 1
                    cursor2.updateRow(row2)
                    print "updated row {}".format(row2[0])
        startNumber = 1
```

Comment: Your task is fraught with potential failures. There is no mandate that an UpdateCursor return records in a particular order if an ORDER BY is not specified. I suggest you change this multiphase update into a series of SearchCursor calls (with ORDER BY) to compile a dictionary of intended results, then use one UpdateCursor to modify values by rowid  lookup.

Comment: the order in my next stage. it will be determinate by the xy location. but for now. how can make this lookup?

Comment: Use a `dictionary`

Comment: Have a look at this [q&a](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374120/auto-increment-by-group-in-arcgis-modelbuilder?r=SearchResults).

Comment: Or this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200150/auto-incrementing-field-based-on-groups-within-feature-class/200154#200154

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are wanting to do...

```
import arcpy

lyrName = r"C:\Users\Moshe\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\D1"    
fields = ["Layer", "RefName"]    
counter = 1
prevFieldValue = ""

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyrName, fields, sql_clause=(None, "ORDER BY Layer, RefName")) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == prevFieldValue:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 1
        row[1] = str(counter)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        prevFieldValue = row[0]
```